# Spring forces with constraints

Tags: spring, rigid-body-dynamics, constrained-dynamics

I am not making progress with understanding with all forces acting on a falling object that collides with an unmovable floor. I want to simulate a car shock absorber attached to a weight falling and contacting a floor.

Each frame of the physics simulation a ray is fired from the base of the shock to measure the contact distance. When there is contact, the spring's compressed distance can be calculated and from there using Hook's Law ([Hooke's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law)), its simple to apply a force to decelerate the weight. With damping this simulation eventually settles down with the spring compressed at a distance to produce 98.1N.

[image]

---

For simplicity, let us assume that all forces are applied to the center of mass of the object and not the contact point. If we look at the following image, its clear that the constraint of the shock obsorber will be solely responsible for decelerating the object to a complete stop. This needs to happen in 1 frame. This is achieved by finding the force needed to decelerate the object to a velocity of 0.

[image]

---

At this stage it looks like there are two forces acting on the system and that they are perpendicular. Once again lets assume all forces are acting on the center of mass and that the contact surface is friction-less. At the same time lets rotate the object 45'.

[image]

How do I go about to calculate the total force to apply, so that the shock contacts the surface, but never overlaps. Plus the spring affects the object.

At 45' it seems that half of this (UP) force comes from the the shock and half from the constraint. The problem here is that, at the frame of contact the spring's compression is 0, so it plays no part. The velocity of the object is big and thus the constraint even at 50% very quickly zeros out the velocity as it halfs each frame. So the spring never compresses.

[image]

Comment: If the object is at an angle it is unlikely the net force acts through the center of mass. There will be torque and so rotation. So you will need to deal with the dynamics of that.

Comment: You need an equation of motion. You need to calculate the motion of the object until it contacts. You need to project the time of contact. If you are using time steps you need to accomodate the inaccuracy involved in that. This is a huge subject in general.